# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1

Tags: pda, cpi, vesting

Making a simple vestment app:

```
pub struct MakeVestment<'info> {

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"ledger", vested_tokens_mint.key().as_ref(), beneficiary.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub ledger: Account<'info, Ledger>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = vestor,
        space = 8 + size_of::<Vestment>(),
        seeds = [b"vestment", ledger.key().as_ref(), &((ledger.vestment_count + 1) as u64).to_le_bytes()],
        bump
    )]
    pub vestment: Account<'info, Vestment>, //parses from bits to vestment struct

    #[account(mut)] 
    pub vestor: Signer<'info>, //=AccountInfo but has to sign it too

    #[account(mut)]
    pub vestor_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account()]
    /// CHECK: TODO
    pub beneficiary: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = vestor,
        seeds = [b"vested-tokens", vestment.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint = vested_tokens_mint,
        token::authority = vested_tokens,
    )]
    pub vested_tokens: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub vested_tokens_mint: Account<'info, Mint>, // mint

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,

    ///CHECK: Validated here.
    #[account(address=system_program::ID)] //so its valid
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>, //accountInfo gives an accounts in BITS
}

pub fn make_vestment(
        ctx: Context<MakeVestment>,
        amount: u64,
        cliff: Option<i64>,
        period: i64,
        num_of_periods: u32,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let vestment: &mut Account<Vestment> = &mut ctx.accounts.vestment;
        let vestor: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.vestor;
        let vesting_start_at = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp;
        let ledger = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger;
        ledger.vestment_count= ledger.vestment_count.checked_add(1).unwrap();


        if amount <=0 { 
            return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidAmount.into());
        }
        if let Some(c) = cliff {
            if c<=0 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidCliff.into());
            }
        }
        if period<=0 {
            return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidPeriod.into());
        }
        if num_of_periods <=0 { 
            return Err(ErrorCode::InvalidNumberOfPeriods.into());
        }


        vestment.vestor = vestor.key();
        vestment.vesting_start_at = vesting_start_at;
        vestment.amount_vested = amount*1000000000;
        vestment.amount_claimed = 0;
        vestment.period_length = period;
        vestment.num_of_periods = num_of_periods;
        vestment.beneficiary = ctx.accounts.beneficiary.key();
        vestment.last_claim_period = None;
        vestment.amount_per_period = vestment.amount_vested.checked_div(vestment.num_of_periods as u64).unwrap();
        vestment.is_active = true;

        if let Some(c) = cliff {
            vestment.cliff_end_at = vestment.vesting_start_at.checked_add(c);
            vestment.vesting_end_at = vestment.cliff_end_at.unwrap()
                .checked_add((num_of_periods as i64).checked_mul(period).unwrap())
                .unwrap();
        } else {
            vestment.cliff_end_at = None;
            vestment.vesting_end_at = vesting_start_at
                .checked_add((num_of_periods as i64).checked_mul(period).unwrap())
                .unwrap();
        }

        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.vestor_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.vested_tokens.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.vestor.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            amount*1000000000 as u64,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
```

The problem is at the end of this:

```
let ledgercina;
        try {
            ledgercina = await program.account.ledger.fetch(ledger.toString());
            console.log(ledgercina);
        } catch (error) {
            const tx0 = await program.rpc.makeLedger({
                accounts: {
                    ledger: ledger,
                    vestor: vestor.publicKey,
                    vestorTokenAccount: vestorTokenAccount,
                    beneficiary: beneficiary.publicKey,
                    vestedTokensMint: tokenMint,
                    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                    rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: [vestor],
            });
            await connection.confirmTransaction(tx0);
            ledgercina = await program.account.ledger.fetch(ledger.toString());
            console.log(ledgercina);
        }
        let ledgerVCount = ledgercina.vestmentCount;
        console.log(ledgerVCount);

        const [oldVestment] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [
                Buffer.from("vestment"),
                ledger.toBuffer(),
                new anchor.BN(ledgerVCount).toBuffer("le", 8),
            ],
            program.programId
        );
        console.log(oldVestment);

        let oldVestmentcina;
        let newVestment = oldVestment;
        try {
            oldVestmentcina = await program.account.vestment.fetch(oldVestment);
            console.log(oldVestmentcina);

            if (oldVestmentcina.isActive == true) {
                console.log("A vestment is already active");
                return;
            }
            ledgerVCount++;
            [newVestment] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [
                    Buffer.from("vestment"),
                    ledger.toBuffer(),
                    new anchor.BN(ledgerVCount).toBuffer("le", 8),
                ],
                program.programId
            );
        } catch (error) {
            [newVestment] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [
                    Buffer.from("vestment"),
                    ledger.toBuffer(),
                    new anchor.BN(1).toBuffer("le", 8),
                ],
                program.programId
            );
        }
        console.log("New vestment:");

        console.log(newVestment);

        const [vestedTokens] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from("vested-tokens"), newVestment.toBuffer()],
            program.programId
        );

        var cliff = 10;
        var numberOfPeriods = 4;
        var period = 5;
        var amount = 10;
        //var vestmentTimeinSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        console.log("Sve ok do sad");
        const tx3 = await program.rpc.makeVestment(
            new anchor.BN(amount),
            null,
            new anchor.BN(period),
            numberOfPeriods,
            {
                accounts: {
                    ledger: ledger,
                    vestment: newVestment,
                    vestor: vestor.publicKey,
                    vestorTokenAccount: vestorTokenAccount,
                    beneficiary: beneficiary.publicKey,
                    vestedTokens: vestedTokens,
                    vestedTokensMint: tokenMint,
                    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                    rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                    systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                },
                signers: [vestor],
            }
        );
```

When calling the makeVestment function there is a problem that is in the name of this post:

```
 Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4465:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4424:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:284:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:144:14)
      at Object.rpc [as makeVestment] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Tokens and balance:

```
const tx1 = await connection.requestAirdrop(
            vestor.publicKey,
            LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        );
        const tx2 = await connection.requestAirdrop(
            beneficiary.publicKey,
            LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
        );

        await connection.confirmTransaction(tx1);
        await connection.confirmTransaction(tx2);

        const tokenMint = await createMint(
            connection,
            vestor,
            vestor.publicKey,
            null,
            0
        );

        const vestorTokenAccount = await createAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            vestor,
            tokenMint,
            vestor.publicKey
        );

        const beneficiaryTokenAccount = await createAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            beneficiary,
            tokenMint,
            beneficiary.publicKey
        );

        const txMint = await mintTo(
            connection,
            vestor,
            tokenMint,
            vestorTokenAccount,
            vestor,
            1000
        );

        await connection.confirmTransaction(txMint);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Educated guess based on what your instruction is doing: the error is probably coming from the `token::transfer`. Everything else would probably be getting an Anchor error message.

`0x1` is `1` in hex

You can see token errors in their source code here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/error.rs#L13

Notice they're numbered (in comments) from 0.
The second error (index 1) is here:

```
/// Insufficient funds for the operation requested.
#[error("Insufficient funds")]
InsufficientFunds,
```

So that'd be my first guess - the account you're sending from doesn't have a sufficient balance. Maybe try using the SPL token library to check the balance in your test is what you expect?

Comment: Thank you man there was a problem in the token::transfer function, you helped us a lot!